# Catching exceptions with tomcat and a servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, error-handling

I have set-up tomcat to catch all my exceptions and pass them to a servlet with the following in web.xml.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>exception</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/exception</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/exception</location>
</error-page>
```

This works fine and I have the servlet logging some information and forwarding to a jsp. However I want to log the URI which caused the exception to be thrown and when I call request.getRequestURI() I get /exception which is my servlet path that's handling logging the exception. How can I get the original URI that caused the exception?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the original uri with

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")
```